# How to use one update function for all fields of a specific model in REST API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am using Django REST Framework and React for a project. I have a API route called `/api/account/user/` which accepts both GET and POST requests (RetrieveUpdateAPIView). Now, in my React front end, I have this function in my actions file that I would like to use to update user data:

```
export const updateUser = (email, name, company, phoneVerified, idVerified) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = getState().auth.token
        let headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        if (token) {
            headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`
        }
        let body = JSON.stringify({email, name, company, phoneVerified, idVerified})

        return fetch('//localhost:8000/api/account/user/', {headers, body, method: 'POST'})
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status < 500) {
                    return res.json().then(data => {
                        return {status: res.status, data}
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Server error.')
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({type: 'USER_UPDATE_SUCCESSFUL', data: res.data})
                    return res.data
                }
                else if (res.status === 403 || res.status === 401) {
                    dispatch({type: 'USER_UPDATE_FAILED', data: res.data})
                    return res.data
                }
                else {
                    dispatch({type: 'USER_UPDATE_FAILED', data: res.data})
                    return res.data
                }
            })
    }
}
```

This function works if I pass all parameters `(email, name, company, phoneVerified, idVerified)`, but for example, if I want to only update `phoneVerified` on a button click event, how do I pass only that parameter? Currently I am doing this:

```
updateUser: (phoneVerified) => dispatch(auth.updateUser(phoneVerified))
```

But the server response is `This field may not be null`. Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the problem of React, it is how you handle in backend code.

You use HTTP POST method in rest API, by default it uses to create one record

You should implement other HTTP method handling for your endpoint, it is PUT method, but with PUT, you still need to send whole object with updated property to update it (**Generally, PUT should use to update the record entirely**)

Another HTTP method fit your case much better, it is PATCH method, just like PUT but you can just send the updated property to server with the record id (**PATCH should use to update the record partially**).

For both case, just **SHOULD**, not **MUST** because it is the standard convention of HTTP, it is not restricted. Even you still can use GET method to create record.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your backend code as well. But the line `JSON.stringify({name, ...})` will render `{name: null, ...}` if name is null. So you're sending null values for all the attributes you're not updating. I would change that code to exclude those attributes altogether.